# Using Toast to deal with exception outside of my Fragment class

Tags: java, android

Currently creating an Android app. I have a class called `Pollen`, on top of my `Fragment` class, and I am dealing with exception handling within this *second* class.

Here is my Pollen class.

```
public static class Pollen
{

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public Pollen(int zipcode, Context context)
    {
                    this.context = context;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
        Document doc;
        try
        {
            // pass address to 
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.wunderground.com/DisplayPollen.asp?Zipcode=" + this.zipcode).get();

            // get "location" from XML
            Element location = doc.select("div.columns").first();
            this.location = location.text();

            // get "pollen type" from XML
            Element pollenType = doc.select("div.panel h3").first();
            this.pollenType = pollenType.text();

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMMM dd, yyyy");

            // add the four items of pollen and dates
            // to its respective list
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Element dates = doc.select("td.text-center.even-four").get(i);
                Element levels = doc.select("td.levels").get(i);

                try
                {
                    pollenMap.put(format.parse(dates.text()), levels.text());
                }
                catch (ParseException e)
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, R.string.toast_parse_fail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, R.string.toast_parse_fail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Since `Pollen` uses Network tasks, it's under an asynchronous thread which is irrelevant to this question.

Whenever `Pollen` is met under an exception, despite the `Toast`, the app would crash.

I was wondering - what is the accepted way to deal with exception on classes outside of the main class?

Comment: post your logcat so we can examine the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is crashing because you are creating a toast from outsied the UI thread.

You cannot create a Toast from a class which is not running on the main thread(UI thread). But you can use the runOnUiThread ([http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)) to execute code on the UI thread from your Pollen class.

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, R.string.toast_parse_fail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
                }
            });
```

For this to work you have to pass the Activity's context to you custom class and use the above method or you can throw exception and catch it from the activity and handle it there.

Comment: I am getting this error: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method runOnUiThread(Runnable) from the type Activity`

Comment: Why is your class Pollen, static?

Comment: Yes, it's static, because if it is not, I get this error: `No enclosing instance of type MainActivity is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type MainActivity (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of MainActivity).` within my `Fragment` class (when I call `Pollen`). If you could suggest me an alternative, that would be terrific.

Comment: So Pollen is an inner class of the MainActivity?

Comment: Yes, it's an inner class of `MainActivity`. It follows this code structure, from a previous question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973612/network-related-tasks-on-a-separate-thread

Comment: try MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.toast_parse_fail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         toast.show();
                 }  where MainActivity is you Activity
             });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54855/discussion-between-thegreencabbage-and-dankodi).